# Run Java in Firefox on Linux

Tags: linux, java, firefox

It is my first time using Linux. What I would like is to run an app called SiteScope that requires Java.

I have already installed Java on my Linux, however when I open the browser I still get the message "A plugin is needed to display this content".

Any help to make it work, using the Oracle JRE (not OpenJDK's Iced Tea), will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Java plugin support in modern browsers is actually discontinued, see an explanation from [support.mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/npapi-plugins?as=u&utm_source=inproduct), [superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1088599) and [Oracle itself](https://java.com/en/download/help/firefox_java.xml) ([the same for Chrome](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml)).

Oracle suggests using Internet Explorer or Safari (admitely not wery useful); or try an alternative browser - not sure how to install it in your distro but [Pale Moon](https://www.palemoon.org/) is a browser based on legacy Firefox, kepping some of it's discontinued APIs (inc. NPAPI needed by the Java plugin) - see [this Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906315/install-java-plugin-in-pale-moon-browser) on how to enable the plugin there.

See the original [guide by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/manual-plugin-install-linux-136395.html) for case you can install an older version of the browser (the latest FF supporting the plugin is 52ESR resp. Chrome 44).

Edit: removed previously suggested IETab extension as I missed the fact it's Windows-only, added Pale Moon suggestion.

Comment: Hello Tomas the problem is that linux doesnt have internet explorer.